# How do i fix PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above")

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pgadmin, libpq

i get an error when I'm trying to connect to postgresql server from a Symfony application. I have everything set up but can't seem to figure out how to upgrade libpq version. I'm using postgresql 13.1